# SQL: How do I use parameter for TOP like in SELECT TOP @amount?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parameters

Using the vs2008 query builder, I’m trying to make a query that gets a parameter for the "`TOP`" Command, and then I face an error "Error in top expression"

Works:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.SomeTable
WHERE SomeColumn = SomeValue
```

Doesn't Work:

```
SELECT TOP @param1 * FROM dbo.SomeTable
WHERE SomeColumn = SomeValue
```

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f9b9354577.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f9b9354577.jpg)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Need parenthesis, and only for SQL Server 2005 and above

```
SELECT TOP (@param1) ...
```

Answer (score 6):

For older versions of SQL Server, you can use:

```
SET ROWCOUNT @NumberOfResults
SELECT * FROM MyTable
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

[However, you should not use this technique on 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx):

> Using SET ROWCOUNT will not affect
>   DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements
>   in the next release of SQL Server
>   (2008). Do not use SET ROWCOUNT with
>   DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements
>   in new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use
>   it. Also, for DELETE, INSERT, and
>   UPDATE statements that currently use
>   SET ROWCOUNT, we recommend that you
>   rewrite them to use the TOP syntax.
>   For more information, see DELETE
>   (Transact-SQL), INSERT (Transact-SQL),
>   or UPDATE (Transact-SQL).